# VB6 to read dataset xml response from vb.net webservice

Tags: xml, vb.net, vb6

I have no idea to do this....

I've surf the net..but none of the code working....

I have this xml response from vb.net webservice:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <DataSet xmlns="http://Wtechwebservice.com.my/">
- <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
- <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
- <xs:complexType>
- <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
- <xs:element name="Table">
+ <xs:complexType>
+ <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="MessageID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="MessageTitle" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="MessageDesc" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="EndDate" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="Repeat" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="Status" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="DateCreated" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="LastUpdated" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" /> 
  <xs:element name="UpdatedBy" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
- <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
- <NewDataSet xmlns="">
- <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
  <MessageID>11</MessageID> 
  <MessageTitle>Happy New Year</MessageTitle> 
  <MessageDesc>New Year is the time to unfold new horizons & realize new dreams</MessageDesc> 
  <StartDate>2011-01-01T16:10:34.963+08:00</StartDate> 
  <EndDate>2011-01-01T16:10:34.963+08:00</EndDate> 
  <Repeat>1</Repeat> 
  <Status>Active</Status> 
  <DateCreated>2010-02-01T16:10:34.963+08:00</DateCreated> 
  <LastUpdated>2010-02-01T16:10:34.963+08:00</LastUpdated> 
  <UpdatedBy>Nosyi</UpdatedBy> 
  </Table>
  </NewDataSet>
  </diffgr:diffgram>
  </DataSet>
```

How do i get my VB6 app to read the result from this XML???

Comment: Have you added a reference to the Microsoft MSXML component to your VB6 project?  And has it been installed on your machine?

Comment: I've added the reference...i use the code to call the .net web service from here : http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=7611             it works wonderful and now i'm stuck at the "extract" the result from the xml...cause the response that i get in VB6 is actually in type string...n I've tried several code for vb6 to read normal xml...it works fine...but not .net dataset xml...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many references of processing XML in vb6. 
My preference is followed in the following article:
http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2000/07/12/vbasic/vb_and_xml.html
It suggests to process the XML via XSLT.

Most basic way is using MSXML. But that is a lot more work compared to using XSLT

Comment: mozillanerd : thanks for the link...i'll try to study that first